# Mongoid persistance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to assign an attribute in my Rails app, however, the assigned data disappears when I re-query the database. Here are my models:

```
class Scent
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :scentid, type: Integer
  field :name
  field :price
  field :category
  field :description
  field :available, type: Boolean

  belongs_to :order
  embedded_in :cartitem

  attr_accessible :name, :price, :category, :available
end

class Cartitem
  include Mongoid::Document  

  field :quantity, type: Integer

  embeds_one :scent
  embedded_in :cart
end
```

Here is the query I am running:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > User.first.cart.cartitems.first.scent
=> nil
1.9.3p194 :060 > User.first.cart.cartitems.first.scent = Scent.first
=> #<Scent _id: 50381e2ec8bafa1710000001, _type: nil, scentid: 1, name: "gold", price"99.99", category: "fresh", description: nil, available: true, order_id: nil>
1.9.3p194 :061 > User.first.cart.cartitems.first.scent
=> nil
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** here are my User and Cart models:

```
  field :firstname
  field :lastname
  field :email
  field :password
  field :password_confirmation
  field :password_digest
  field :stripeid
  field :remember_token

  has_many :orders
  embeds_many :address
  embeds_one :cart

  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :firstname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :lastname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness:{case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  index({email:1}, {unique: true, name: 'email_index'})

  private
    def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
end

class Cart
  include Mongoid::Document  

  embedded_in :user
  embeds_many :cartitems

end
```

Comment: accept the answer among any of the two by clicking on right mark below voting option...

Comment: User.first.cart.cartitems.first.scent = Scent.new gets stored, however, Scent.first does not. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your answer

```
user = User.first.cart.cartitems.first
user.scent = Scent.first
user.save!
```

it will work fine.

Comment: sorry, this does not work. when I query User.first.cart.cartitem.first.scent again I still get nil

Comment: ohh I didn't checked it properly before your model structure is wrong `Scent` is a embedded document so it can't be `belongs_to` any other model. Thats the basics of mongodb that embedded document can't be referenced in any other model. First change that and try it should work then...

Answer (score 3):

You didn't call `save` to the model.